# Automatic override of parent methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm trying to add a wrapper to each method in a class by subclassing it, and reassigning them in the constructor of the new class, however i'm getting the same reference for all subclassed methods, how is this possible?

```py
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

    def bar(self):
        print("bar")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        methods = [
            (method_name, getattr(self, method_name)) for method_name in dir(self) if not method_name.startswith('_')
        ]

        for (method_name, f) in methods:

            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print('wrapped')
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

            setattr(self, method_name, wrapper)


b = B()

b.foo()
>>> wrapped
>>> foo

b.bar()
>>> wrapped
>>> foo
```

Comment: @Axe319 right! they are bound to outer scope and hold a reference to the last value. thanks, can u submit it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a spin on a common python gotcha, [late binding closures.](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

What is happening is the last value of `f` is being bound to all your wrapped methods.

A common workaround is binding your changing variable to a keyword argument or using `functools.partial`.
For your example you can use it as a keyword argument.

```
class A:
    def foo(self, baz='foo'):
        print(baz)

    def bar(self, baz='bar'):
        print(baz)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        methods = [
            (method_name, getattr(self, method_name)) for method_name in dir(self) if not method_name.startswith('_')
        ]

        for (method_name, f) in methods:
            # here you can use an implied private keyword argument
            # to minimize the chance of conflicts
            def wrapper(*args, _f=f, **kwargs):
                print('wrapped')
                return _f(*args, **kwargs)

            setattr(self, method_name, wrapper)


b = B()
b.foo()
b.foo('baz')
b.foo(baz='baz')
b.bar()
```

I added a few more calls to your method to demonstrate that it still works with different forms of calls.